# Running JMeter script using VBScript as automated test in HP ALM

Tags: vbscript, automation, jmeter, loadrunner, alm

So I'm trying to run JMeter from ALM. I have a bunch of scripts that will do load testing. At this point, I'm grasping at straws to get anything working. Originally I wanted to use LoadRunner, but I can't figure out how to actually run the scripts I have developed in that application either.

That said: I have written some code just to attempt to run the JMeter application with the relevant script. As I understand it, ALM runs the VBS locally, so local paths should work, and running software installed on a local machine should work...

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Exec "C:\Users\[path]\apache-jmeter-2.12\bin\jmeter.bat -t C:\Users\[path]\script.jmx"
```

This executes fine, but when looking at it, nothing appears. Ideally I'd have this run with no GUI (-n flag for jmeter), but I want to at least verify that the thing even starts up.

Currently nothing is happening, and I can't figure out what to do. I've attempted loops that wait until something happens, but they end up being infinite loops.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Or...if you know of a resource that could actually help run either LoadRunner or JMeter scripts from ALM, I would be so grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your ALM script doesn't respect underlying OS properties like `JAVA_HOME` or you don't have `java` executable in your `PATH` variable.

Try changing your line to look as follows:

```
objShell.Exec "c:\java\bin\java.exe -jar C:\Users\[path]\apache-jmeter-2.12\bin\ApacheJMeter.jar -t C:\Users\[path]\script.jmx"
```

to see how it goes.

By the way, there are several more ways of launching JMeter test, to learn about options check out [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide, hopefully it will help to identify and apply the best integration approach.

Comment: how can we run JMeter in non gui mode using objShell.Exec

Answer (score 0):

Why......What is optimal for performance unit tests is not optimal for performance business tests.  You also have people building tests for JMETER who it is not their primary focus to engage in performance testing. The requirements will be soft, the data sparse, the liberties on think time and pacing great. You are looking at a low value path.  This perspective comes from a reformed developer.

Just rebuild them natively. Your value will be higher and a better match to the requirements you are looking to validate.  Need a starting point?  Execute your JMETER scripts with the target of your LoadRunner recording proxy.   Input = JMETER requests, output = native LoadRunner code (in C).  No funky library compromises for trying to have one tool execute another one.

If you are hellbent on pursuing this path and cannot/will not be dissuaded then consider the JAVA template virtual user.  This is likely your best path, assuming you are licensed for it. You will also find that the odds are close to certainty that you will spend more time achieving a stable model than you will in just rebuilding the existing test code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Exec """C:\Program Files\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\JMeter.Bat"" -n -t ""C:\Program Files\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\templates\DMS_APP.jmx"""
```